# Notebook won’t post with 4Gb RAM

Tags: laptop, memory, acer-aspire, post, ddr3

I'm trying to upgrade the RAM memory of an old notebook from 1x2Gb to 1x4Gb:

2Gb (top stick)/4Gb (bottom stick) DDR3 SO-DIMM

[image: DDR3 SO-DIMM]

According to the manufacturer specs, this notebook supports 8Gb max (2x4Gb).
Furthermore, if both slots are filled, they must have modules of the same size.

However, regardless of what slot I insert the 4Gb or leave empty, the notebook doesn't POST.
All I get is an unknown beep code error (`-..   ---..` | [audio](https://streamable.com/6qptgt)).
**Note: I'm not trying to upgrade to 6Gb (2Gb+4Gb).**

I'm sure both sticks are working because I can run them on other notebooks.

##### QUESTIONS

- Why this notebook doesn't POST with one single 4Gb stick?
- What parameters should I check in order to guarantee compatibility between the RAM stick and such notebook?

---

##### Hardware Specification

- **Product Name:** Acer Aspire E1-421
- **Processor:** AMD E1-1200 Dual-core APU @ 1.40 GHz
- [Datasheet](https://www.acer.com/datasheets/2013/4876/E1-421/NX.M25AL.004.html)
- [Service Manual | System Memory](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/483151/Acer-Aspire-E1-421.html?page=35#manual)

- **2Gb Module Info**

  ```
    root@debian:~# dmidecode --type memory
    # dmidecode 3.3
    Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
    SMBIOS 2.7 present.

    Handle 0x0005, DMI type 5, 20 bytes
    Memory Controller Information
        Error Detecting Method: None
        Error Correcting Capabilities:
            None
        Supported Interleave: One-way Interleave
        Current Interleave: One-way Interleave
        Maximum Memory Module Size: 8192 MB
        Maximum Total Memory Size: 16384 MB
        Supported Speeds:
            Other
            Unknown
            70 ns
            60 ns
            50 ns
        Supported Memory Types:
            Other
            Unknown
            Standard
            FPM
            SIMM
            Burst EDO
        Memory Module Voltage: 3.3 V
        Associated Memory Slots: 2
            0x0006
            0x0007
        Enabled Error Correcting Capabilities:
            None
            Single-bit Error Correcting
            Double-bit Error Correcting
            Error Scrubbing

    Handle 0x0006, DMI type 6, 12 bytes
    Memory Module Information
        Socket Designation: DIMM 0
        Bank Connections: None
        Current Speed: 1 ns
        Type: DIMM
        Installed Size: 2048 MB (Single-bank Connection)
        Enabled Size: 2048 MB (Single-bank Connection)
        Error Status: OK

    Handle 0x0007, DMI type 6, 12 bytes
    Memory Module Information
        Socket Designation: DIMM 1
        Bank Connections: None
        Current Speed: Unknown
        Type: None
        Installed Size: Not Installed
        Enabled Size: Not Installed
        Error Status: OK

    Handle 0x0013, DMI type 16, 23 bytes
    Physical Memory Array
        Location: System Board Or Motherboard
        Use: System Memory
        Error Correction Type: None
        Maximum Capacity: 2 GB
        Error Information Handle: Not Provided
        Number Of Devices: 2

    Handle 0x0014, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
    Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x0013
        Error Information Handle: Not Provided
        Total Width: 64 bits
        Data Width: 64 bits
        Size: 2 GB
        Form Factor: SODIMM
        Set: None
        Locator: DIMM 0
        Bank Locator: CHANNEL A
        Type: DDR3
        Type Detail: Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered)
        Speed: 667 MT/s
        Manufacturer: Not Specified
        Serial Number: 030EF5FB
        Asset Tag: Asset Tag: 
        Part Number: SH564568FH8NZPHSCR
        Rank: 1
        Configured Memory Speed: 533 MT/s

    Handle 0x0015, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
    Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x0013
        Error Information Handle: Not Provided
        Total Width: Unknown
        Data Width: Unknown
        Size: No Module Installed
        Form Factor: <OUT OF SPEC>
        Set: None
        Locator: DIMM 1
        Bank Locator: CHANNEL A
        Type: Unknown
        Type Detail: Unknown
        Speed: Unknown
        Manufacturer: Empty
        Serial Number: Empty
        Asset Tag: Asset Tag: 
        Part Number: Empty
        Rank: Unknown
        Configured Memory Speed: Unknown
  ```

- **4Gb Module Info | View from another notebook**

  ```
    root@debian:~# dmidecode --type memory
    # dmidecode 3.3
    Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
    SMBIOS 2.7 present.

    Handle 0x0010, DMI type 16, 23 bytes
    Physical Memory Array
        Location: System Board Or Motherboard
        Use: System Memory
        Error Correction Type: None
        Maximum Capacity: 16 GB
        Error Information Handle: Not Provided
        Number Of Devices: 4

    Handle 0x0011, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
    Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x0010
        Error Information Handle: Not Provided
        Total Width: Unknown
        Data Width: Unknown
        Size: No Module Installed
        Form Factor: <OUT OF SPEC>
        Set: None
        Locator: DIMM0
        Bank Locator: BANK 0
        Type: Unknown
        Type Detail: Unknown
        Speed: Unknown
        Manufacturer: Empty
        Serial Number: Empty
        Asset Tag: Unknown
        Part Number: Empty
        Rank: Unknown
        Configured Memory Speed: Unknown

    Handle 0x0012, DMI type 6, 12 bytes
    Memory Module Information
        Socket Designation: DIMM0
        Bank Connections: None
        Current Speed: Unknown
        Type: None
        Installed Size: Not Installed
        Enabled Size: Not Installed
        Error Status: OK

    Handle 0x0013, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
    Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x0010
        Error Information Handle: Not Provided
        Total Width: Unknown
        Data Width: Unknown
        Size: No Module Installed
        Form Factor: <OUT OF SPEC>
        Set: None
        Locator: DIMM1
        Bank Locator: BANK 1
        Type: Unknown
        Type Detail: Unknown
        Speed: Unknown
        Manufacturer: Empty
        Serial Number: Empty
        Asset Tag: Unknown
        Part Number: Empty
        Rank: Unknown
        Configured Memory Speed: Unknown

    Handle 0x0014, DMI type 6, 12 bytes
    Memory Module Information
        Socket Designation: DIMM1
        Bank Connections: None
        Current Speed: Unknown
        Type: None
        Installed Size: Not Installed
        Enabled Size: Not Installed
        Error Status: OK

    Handle 0x0015, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
    Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x0010
        Error Information Handle: Not Provided
        Total Width: 64 bits
        Data Width: 64 bits
        Size: 4 GB
        Form Factor: DIMM
        Set: None
        Locator: DIMM1
        Bank Locator: BANK 2
        Type: DDR3
        Type Detail: Synchronous
        Speed: 666 MT/s
        Manufacturer: Unknown
        Serial Number: 00000000
        Asset Tag: Unknown
        Part Number: Not Specified
        Rank: 2
        Configured Memory Speed: 1333 MT/s

    Handle 0x0016, DMI type 6, 12 bytes
    Memory Module Information
        Socket Designation: DIMM1
        Bank Connections: None
        Current Speed: Unknown
        Type: DIMM
        Installed Size: 4096 MB (Single-bank Connection)
        Enabled Size: 4096 MB (Single-bank Connection)
        Error Status: OK

    Handle 0x0018, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
    Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x0010
        Error Information Handle: Not Provided
        Total Width: Unknown
        Data Width: Unknown
        Size: No Module Installed
        Form Factor: <OUT OF SPEC>
        Set: None
        Locator: DIMM3
        Bank Locator: BANK 3
        Type: Unknown
        Type Detail: Unknown
        Speed: Unknown
        Manufacturer: Empty
        Serial Number: Empty
        Asset Tag: Unknown
        Part Number: Empty
        Rank: Unknown
        Configured Memory Speed: Unknown

    Handle 0x0019, DMI type 6, 12 bytes
    Memory Module Information
        Socket Designation: DIMM3
        Bank Connections: None
        Current Speed: Unknown
        Type: None
        Installed Size: Not Installed
        Enabled Size: Not Installed
        Error Status: OK

    Handle 0x001B, DMI type 5, 24 bytes
    Memory Controller Information
        Error Detecting Method: None
        Error Correcting Capabilities:
            None
        Supported Interleave: One-way Interleave
        Current Interleave: One-way Interleave
        Maximum Memory Module Size: 8192 MB
        Maximum Total Memory Size: 32768 MB
        Supported Speeds:
            Other
        Supported Memory Types:
            Other
        Memory Module Voltage: Unknown
        Associated Memory Slots: 4
            0x0012
            0x0014
            0x0016
            0x0019
        Enabled Error Correcting Capabilities:
            None
  ```

Comment: According to the manufacturer specs, this notebook supports a maximum of 8Gb (2x4Gb).   ......   Did you update BIOS?  You may need to for the computer to see the memory.

Comment: @John > "Did you update BIOS?" Yes, I'm using the latest BIOS available at the manufacturer website.

Comment: I suggest you contact Acer Support and check with them

Comment: @John > "contact Acer Support" Therefore, at first glance, you have the impression that the 4Gb stick should have worked?

Comment: You said a 4GB stick did not work. That is why I suggest contacting Support because the 4GB stick should have worked.  Did you use Acer Memory?

Comment: @John > "Did you use Acer Memory?" Not sure. Moreover, didn't even know Acer manufactured RAM memories. According to the images I've posted, doesn't seem they are from Acer.

Comment: Acer doesn't manufacture RAM modules. But some laptops (not only Acer) had a small list of truly compatible memory. AMD's APU are notoriously "picky".

Comment: And funny thing: Although Acer mentions DDR3 (1.5V) and you Kingston matches, the original 2GB module seems to DDR3L (1.35V) (not sure, couldn't find much about that "made in Brazil" memory) and Crucial actually says to use DDR3L only: https://www.crucial.com/compatible-upgrade-for/acer/aspire-e1-421#memory

Comment: @ChanganAuto > "the original 2GB module seems to DDR3L (1.35V) (not sure, couldn't find much about that "made in Brazil" memory)" I couldn't find a definitive answer for that too. But, AFAIK, this module should be DDR3 1.5V.